# Creating a comboboxitem from a static resource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following resource defined in a listview:

```
<local:FillPatternDefinition x:Key="deleteItem" TypeName="Delete Regions" ItsId="-1"/>
```

and a combobox hosted by the listview defined this way:

```
<ComboBox
        Name="changeComboBox"
        Width="100"
        DisplayMemberPath="TypeName"
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <ComboBoxItem Foreground="Black" Background="Salmon" Content="{StaticResource deleteItem}"/>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource theComboBoxDataView}}" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

The problem is the comboxitem in the composite collection. In the drop down box I see the class name (FillPatternDefinition) but when I select it the TypeName "Delete Regions" appears properly in the combobox. The collectioncontainer holds the same class of items but the items all appear and work normally.

Do I need to wrap the static resource in some other kind of class to get it to work right in the drop down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not explicitly create a `ComboBoxItem` in the CompositeCollection, because the ComboBox internally creates ComboBoxItems for each element in its `ItemsSource` collection. Use a `StaticResource` instead:

```
<ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
        <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="deleteItem"/>
        <CollectionContainer
            Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource theComboBoxDataView}}" />
    </CompositeCollection>
</ComboBox.ItemsSource>
```

Setting the `Foreground` and `Background` of the first item could be done in an `ItemContainerStyle` of the ComboBox.